# Select2 Dropdowns intermittent loading of previous data

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I am struggling with an issue regarding dropdowns for an edit page I have created. The text fields are fine and always load, however the dropdowns are really intermittent and sometimes load some of them, sometimes none of them, sometimes all of them. I can't for the life of me work out why. Clearly I've done something stupid, so if anyone is able to help me. I have made a test example and created a fake customer, just to protect data etc. If any more code is required please do let me know. I can only assume the issue lies in my load_case_info_for_editing_response. Just for additional context, this runs on a Node.JS server and a PythonFastAPI for Queries etc. I have tested console logging the data and it does actually pull it. So I assume it has to be HTML or JavaScript Side.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Edit Case Information</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--Template Universal Links-->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/media/icons/Asteria_Icon_Blue.ico">
        <!--Scripts to load header and footer-->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/universal_js/load_header_footer.js" defer></script>-->
        <!--Master CSS Link-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/universal_css/master.css">
        <!--Current File Links-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/edit_case.css">

        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/edit_case.js" defer></script>
        <!--Icons--->
<!--        <link href='https://css.gg/bell.css' rel='stylesheet'>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/fontawesome/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/loading_css_animations/cube_loader.css">
<!--        <link href='https://css.gg/arrow-long-up-c.css' rel='stylesheet'>-->
<!--        <link href='https://css.gg/arrow-long-down-c.css' rel='stylesheet'>-->

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <!--Header to be loaded in here by js-->
        </div>
        <div id="edit-case-layout-container">
            <div id="edit-case-layout" class="display-card">
                <div id="edit-title-container">
                    <h2>Edit Case</h2>
                    <button onclick="history.back()">Cancel</button>
                    <button id="edit-button-submit" onclick="submit_edit_case();">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <h4>Case Title</h4>
                <input id="edit-case-title" type="text" placeholder="A brief title of the case..." autofocus>
                <div id="edit-form-container">
                    <div id="edit-form-left-container">
                        <h4>Customer</h4>
                        <select id="edit-case-form-select-customer">
                            <option></option>
                        </select>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#edit-case-form-select-customer').select2({
                                    placeholder: "Select a customer",
                                    allowClear: false,
                                    width: '100%',
                                    dropdownParent: $('#edit-form-left-container')
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                        <div class="edit-form-row">
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item">
                                <h4>Customer Forename</h4>
                                <input id="edit-case-form-customer-forename" type="text" placeholder="e.g. John">
                            </div>
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item create-form-row-item-last">
                                <h4>Customer Surname</h4>
                                <input id="edit-case-form-customer-surname" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Smith">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="edit-form-row">
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item">
                                <h4>Alternative Email</h4>
                                <input id="edit-case-form-alternate-email" type="text" placeholder="e.g. j.smith@domain.com">
                            </div>
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item create-form-row-item-last">
                                <h4>Alternative Phone</h4>
                                <input id="edit-case-form-alternate-phone" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 01234 567 890">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="edit-case-form-spacer"></div>
                        <div class="edit-form-row">
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item">
                                <h4>Case Source</h4>
                                <select id="edit-case-form-select-case-source">
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#edit-case-form-select-case-source').select2({
                                            placeholder: "Select a case source",
                                            allowClear: false,
                                            width: '100%',
                                            dropdownParent: $('#edit-form-left-container')
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
                            <div class="edit-form-row-item edit-form-row-item-last">
                                <h4>Case Priority</h4>
                                <select id="edit-case-form-select-case-priority">
                                    <option></option>
                                </select>
                                <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $('#edit-case-form-select-case-priority').select2({
                                            placeholder: "Select a case priority",
                                            allowClear: false,
                                            width: '100%',
                                            dropdownParent: $('#edit-form-left-container')
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="edit-form-right-container">
                    <h4>Case Description</h4>
                    <textarea id="edit-case-form-case-description" placeholder="A description of what the case is about..."></textarea>
                    <h4>Attachments</h4>
                    <p>Attachments are under development</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <!--Header to be loaded in here by js-->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
    case_source_dropdown = $('#edit-case-form-select-case-source'),
    case_priority_dropdown = $('#edit-case-form-select-case-priority');




/*
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
[Customers Dropdown Update]
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
*/
function update_customer_dropdown() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        customer_dropdown.append(
            new Option(data[i].type_of_customer + " | " + data[i].customer_name,data[i].customer_id)
        ).trigger('change')
    }
}

let customer_dropdown_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
customer_dropdown_request.addEventListener("load", update_customer_dropdown);
customer_dropdown_request.open("POST", "/api/customers");
customer_dropdown_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
customer_dropdown_request.send();


/*
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
[Case Source Dropdown Update]
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
*/
function update_case_source_dropdown() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (let i=0; i<data["data"].length; i++) {
        case_source_dropdown.append(
            new Option(data["data"][i],data["data"][i])
        ).trigger('change')
    }
}

let case_source_dropdown_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
case_source_dropdown_request.addEventListener("load", update_case_source_dropdown);
case_source_dropdown_request.open("POST", "/api/cases/case_source_data");
case_source_dropdown_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
case_source_dropdown_request.send();





/*
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
[Case Priority Dropdown Update]
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
*/
function update_case_priority_dropdown() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    for (let i=0; i<data["data"].length; i++) {
        case_priority_dropdown.append(
            new Option(data["data"][i],data["data"][i])
        ).trigger('change')
    }
}

let case_priority_dropdown_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
case_priority_dropdown_request.addEventListener("load", update_case_priority_dropdown);
case_priority_dropdown_request.open("POST", "/api/cases/case_priority_data");
case_priority_dropdown_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
case_priority_dropdown_request.send();



/*
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
[Load case for editing]
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
*/
function load_case_info_for_editing() {
    let load_case_info_for_editing_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    load_case_info_for_editing_request.addEventListener("load", load_case_info_for_editing_response);
    load_case_info_for_editing_request.open("POST", "view_case/get_case");
    load_case_info_for_editing_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    let data = {
        case_id: new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('case_id')
    }

    load_case_info_for_editing_request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

load_case_info_for_editing()

function load_case_info_for_editing_response() {
    let current_case = JSON.parse(this.responseText)[0];
    console.log("Current Case Data:", current_case);

    document.getElementById('edit-case-title').value = current_case.case_title;

    customer_dropdown.val(current_case.customer);
    customer_dropdown.trigger('change');

    case_source_dropdown.val(current_case.case_source);
    case_source_dropdown.trigger('change');

    case_priority_dropdown.val(current_case.case_priority);
    case_priority_dropdown.trigger('change');

    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-forename").value = current_case.customer_forename;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-surname").value = current_case.customer_surname;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-email").value = current_case.alternate_email;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-phone").value = current_case.alternate_phone;
    document.getElementById("edit-case-form-case-description").value = current_case.case_description;
}
/*
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
[Send Edits to update case]
▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬
*/


function submit_edit_case() {
    let new_edit_case_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    new_edit_case_request.addEventListener("load", submit_edit_case_response);
    new_edit_case_request.open("POST", "/api/cases/edit_case");
    new_edit_case_request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let data = {
        "case_id": new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('case_id'),
        "case_title": document.getElementById("edit-case-title").value,
        "customer": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-select-customer").value,
        "customer_forename": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-forename").value,
        "customer_surname": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-customer-surname").value,
        "alternate_email": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-email").value,
        "alternate_phone": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-alternate-phone").value,
        "case_source": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-select-case-source").value,
        "case_priority": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-select-case-priority").value,
        "case_description": document.getElementById("edit-case-form-case-description").value,
    }

    new_edit_case_request.send(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function submit_edit_case_response() {
    let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    if (data['response'] === "Success") {
        alert("Case updated successfully");
        history.back();
    } else {
        alert(data['response']);
    }
}
```

[image: Edit page with some of the dropdowns not loading]

Comment: In my computer, the 3 dropdowns are always working (open on click) but showing no result.

Comment: Hi, well - for whatever reason, sometimes they load and sometimes they don't. I'm not sure if I can give you anymore information than that :( does that help?

Comment: @Ewan --  We need more debugging details.  You should use your console and watch for the times nothing loads to see if there is an error.  My guess is you have an asynchronous function or callback that is "luckily" firing in the correct order most of the time and intermittently misfiring, probably resulting in a "cannot this of undefined" error.  Watch your console, and report back.

Comment: I don't appear to be getting any kid of errors in the console that are related to this issue at all - or really any error. Not sure what I should try next?

Comment: Edit: After ages with it open the error comes through as this "edit_case:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"

Answer (score 1):

So after trying different potential solutions out, a counter was created which would increase as the dropdowns loaded, the data for the case would only load once the dropdowns had loaded all the select2 options (i.e. counter reached value of 3). So essentially, it was an asynchronous issue, and this isn't a brilliant solution, but one that works. So we take it.